# es6 for loop not looping

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

I am trying to get a simple ES6 for-loop working but cant figure out why its not running.

I've copied an example from developer.mozilla docs and I've also tried it with the eslinter version which is below:
I have also added a let i = 0; above. All it renders/logs is i = 0 and wont increment. 
the eslint version is here: [eslint site](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-plusplus)

```
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    console.log('i', i);
    return <p>component {i}</p>;
  }
```

Edit: ok got the values coming back in the log as i=0, i=1, etc... but to get them into a component each? i tried the push into array and mapping through to get the components out but i get no error and nothing appearing, even if i try just getting a value out.

```
const nbPageArray = [];
  let i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < nbPages; i += 1) {
    console.log('i', i);
    nbPageArray.push(<p>component {i}</p>);
  }
  console.log('array', nbPageArray);
  nbPageArray.map(a => <p>{a.type}</p>);
}
```

final working version:

```
const nbPageArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < nbPages; i += 1) {
  nbPageArray.push({ page: i + 1 });
}
return nbPageArray.map(a =>
  <li className="page-item"><a className="page-link">{a.page}</a></li>,
);
```

Comment: your `return` is going to exit from the function at the first itheration

Comment: You return the function at the first iteration. Hence it won't loop.

Comment: event it didn't return it will only loop once since you are adding 10 to `i`

Comment: please return nbPageArray.map(a => <p>{a.type}</p>);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Main issue is**  `i += 10;`

**That should be** `1 += 1;`

And You should return array of elements :

```
var p_tags = [];
for (i = 0; i < 10;  i += 1) {
    console.log('i', i);
    p_tags.push(<p>component {i}</p>);
}
return p_tags;
```

---

Edited question's answer :

First Error:

`const nbPageArray = [];` should be `var nbPageArray = [];`

Second You are not returning the array so change your code to this

```
return nbPageArray.map(a => <p>{a.type}</p>);
```

Comment: this will also only run once, since you're incrementing `i` by 10

Comment: @rebecca, sorry I didn't see that as I was just focusing on return ; Thanks.

Comment: no worries, the return was the obvious error, didn't catch the incrementing issue at first too

Answer (score 0):

If you `return` from your for loop, you will exit the current function, you are also incrementing i by 10 each trip so you will exit the loop after one round either way.

If you are trying to print a string with the value of `i` ten times you could try using template string like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
  console.log('i', i);
  console.log(`<p>component ${i}</p>`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are returning from the loop and also incrementing by 10. The loop will execute only once.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, the `return` inside the for loop is going to exit from the function at the first iteration.

You can do something like this instead:

```
const result = Array(10).fill().map((_, i) =>
  <p>component {i}</p>
);
```

Or

```
const result = [...Array(10)].map((_, i) =>
  <p>component {i}</p>
);
```